# How to get the filname dynamically from its 'p' tag

Tags: javascript, jquery

Here is my code. from the searched content I'm trying to get that 'p' tag's index in it's parent file and its parent filename. From the code if i click 7th  'p' tag  from the file like 2.html. i need to get the index as 7 and the filename as '2.html'.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
    <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes">
    <meta
      name="viewport"
      content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no"
    />


    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.7.2.min.js"></script>



        $(document).ready(function(){                   



                var j1 = $('<div class = "cl1 cl">', {
                    'data-src': 'components/1.html'
                }).load('components/1.html');
                var j2 = $('<div class = "cl2 cl">', {
                    'data-src': 'components/2.html'
                }).load('components/2.html');
                var j3 = $('<div class = "cl3 cl">', {
                    'data-src': 'components/3.html'
                }).load('components/3.html');

                $("#search_content").append(j1);
                $("#search_content").append(j2);
                $("#search_content").append(j3);

            $('#search').click(function() { 

                var p = $("p").length;
                    //alert(p); 

                //var p = $("p").length;
                //alert(p);
                var keyword = $('.qid').val().replace(/\s+/g, " ").replace(/\s+$|^\s+/g, "");  
                var containsString = keyword;
                //alert(containsString);    
                if(keyword == ""){                  
                }else{
                    $('#search_content').css('overflow-y','scroll');
                }
                 //alert(containsString);

                $("p").removeClass('show');
                containsString = "p:contains("+containsString+")".replace("p:contains()","");                   
                //console.log(containsString);
                //alert(containsString);
                $(containsString).addClass('show');
                $('h2').show();
                $('.show').click(function () {

                    var cl = $('.show').closest(".cl");
                    var ps = cl.find('p');
                    var occurance = ps.index(this) + 1;
                    alert('occurance'+occurance);
                    alert(cl.data('src'));

                });



                if ($('.qid').val() == ''){
                    $('p').removeClass('show');

                }
            });


        });

    </script>

  </head>

  <body>



    <div id="displaybox2" style = "display:none;">
        <input class="qid" type="text"/><button id = "search">Search</button>       
        <div id = "search_content">

        </div>
    </div>
  </body>

</html>
```

Comment: You are going to get downvotes, because it's not clear what you are asking. There is no 7th `<p>` tag in the above code, or even any `<p>` tag at all. You need to give examples of the tags users might click, including all of the content of those tags.

Comment: duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20603592/how-to-get-the-file-name-from-its-p-tag

Comment: @ArunPJohny Thats me only. Someone has put downvotes

Comment: @ArunPJohny your answers are very helpful. how to continue to chat. can u send your mail id.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Write your j1/j2/j3 definitions as:

`var j1 = $('<div class = "cl1 cl" data-src="components/1.html">').load('components/1.html');`

Then

`$(specific p selector here).closest('div[data-src]').attr('data-src')`

This would give you 'components/1.html' (for a `p` tag in j1).
For the index, maybe something like

`$(specific p selector here).prevAll('p').length + 1`

Comment: its getting the filename. but the index is getting wrong

Comment: Is the index completely wrong? Or +-1 or something

Comment: Thanks. But the index is getting wrong. Can u help me

Comment: It get +4 for first file. +5 for 2nd file

Comment: Make sure your `$(specific p selector here)` is returning just one element. If you're getting more than one element, then `prevAll` would return the preceding siblings of All those elements, which would  obviously give a nonsense index value

Comment: Im using var h = $(this).prevAll().length + 1; inside $('.show').click function

Comment: Could you create a fiddle for this? Be much easier to find the problem. Before that, try `$(this).prevAll('p').length + 1`

Comment: Thanks. $(this).prevAll('p').length + 1; is working correctly. Thanks a lot